# How to drop Pandas DataFrame rows with condition to keep specific column value

Tags: python, pandas

I know similar questions have been asked before, but they didn't quite seem to help with my issue so I decided to ask a new question.

What I have are three separate DataFrames - let's call them `a`, `b`, and `c` - that are merged into one large dataframe. In each of these three DataFrames, there may be duplicate pairs of column values that I want to drop, but the condition is that if the pair belongs to DataFrame `c`, then I want to keep that pair. For example:

```
>>> a.head()
    unit    value    target
 0   3       23       'a'
 1   2       24       'd'
 2   8       56       'e'
 3   9       89       'p'
 4   0       32       'q'

>>> b.head()
    unit    value    target
 0   3       34       'a'
 1   2       36       'd'
 2   8       23       'a'
 3   9       89       'p'
 4   0       48       'm'

>>> c.head()
    unit    value    target
 0   3       34       'a'
 1   5       23       'a'
 2   2       48       'm'
 3   9       56       'e'
 4   0       98       'z'
```

The particular columns that I'm looking to find duplicates in is (`value`, `target`). As you can tell, there are a total of four different duplicate scenarios: (`a`, `b`), (`b`, `c`), (`a`, `c`), (`a`, `b`, `c`). In the above example, the (`value`, `target`) pairs that would occur for each scenario would be: (`89`, `'p'`), (`34`, `'a'`), (`56`, `'e'`), and (`23`, `'a'`), respectively.

If the duplicate occurs in (`a`, `b`) it's not a huge problem because I can just simply choose from one of them, but if it occurs in any of the other three scenarios, I want to choose the pair from `c` and discard the duplicates from `a` and/or `b`.

The original idea that I had was to use the following code:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([a, b, c], axis=0)
>>> df.drop_duplicates(subset=['value', 'target'], keep='last', inplace=True)
```

Since we're adding `c` to the end of the concatenated DataFrame `df`, we're guaranteed to retain that value should it occur as a duplicate. However, I was wondering if anyone knew of a way where if (`a`, `b`) were to occur, we would select one by random and if `c` is included then we always choose `c`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

we can use `sample` before we combine with `c`

```
a_b=pd.concat([a,b]).sample(n=len(a)+len(b))
new=pd.concat([a_b,c]).drop_duplicates(['value', 'target'], keep='last')
new
Out[11]: 
   unit  value target
1     2     24    'd'
4     0     32    'q'
3     9     89    'p'
1     2     36    'd'
0     3     34    'a'
1     5     23    'a'
2     2     48    'm'
3     9     56    'e'
4     0     98    'z'
```